# floatThead and bootstrap downdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So I am trying to have a dropdown in a fixed header. floatThead works well for fixing to the top, but the dropdown can only display the elements that fit in the header of the table because of the wrapping overflow:hidden as part of floatThead. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muruadvm/20/). I tried upping/downing the z-index to no avail. Is it possible or should I get rid of the dropdown? (It isn't all together necessary, but a nice bonus if it could work).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sticky-header').floatThead({zIndex: 1001});
});
```

Comment: `div.floatThead-container {overflow:unset;}` I was just writing this when Jaydo beat me down. Oh. But still tricky.

Comment: @kecer I haven't seen `unset` before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jaydo: Not really relevant, could have been inherit,  or visible, in this case it would work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `.floatThead-container` to have `overflow: visible` and use `!important` to override the inline styling.

```
div.floatThead-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muruadvm/21/)